# athena concatenate multiple columns into one json string

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

My requirement:

I have a table called `students` with this schema

```
-----------------------
| id name age city   |
-----------------------
| 1  a     12  city1 |
| 2  b     13  city2 |
| 3  c     14  city3 |
| 4  d     15  city4 |
----------------------
```

I want  a query which will return the below result

```
---------------------------------------
 id               details            
---------------------------------------
 1  {name: a , age: 12 , city:city1} 
 2  {name: b , age: 13 , city:city2} 
 3  {name: c , age: 14 , city:city3} 
 4  {name: d  ,age: 15 , city:city4} 
---------------------------------------
```

I tried the below query

```
select id,(name,age,city) as details from students
```

and received this output

```
---------------------------------------
 id               details            
---------------------------------------
 1  {field0: a , field1: 12 , field2:city1} 
 2  {field0: b , field1: 13 , field2:city2} 
 3  {field0: c , field1: 14 , field2:city3} 
 4  {field0: d  ,field1: 15 , field2:city4} 
---------------------------------------
```

Can anyone tell me how I can get rid of this `field0,field1,field1,` and instead have actual column names?

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't specify the DB engine and you added the tag for Amazon Athena, here is the syntax for Athena:

```
WITH students AS
( SELECT 1 as id, 'a' as name, 12 as age, 'city1' as city UNION ALL 
  SELECT 2, 'b', 13, 'city2' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'c', 14, 'city3' UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 'd', 15, 'city4')

SELECT CAST(MAP_FROM_ENTRIES(
    ARRAY[
      ('name', name), 
      ('age', cast(age as varchar)), 
      ('city', city)
    ]) AS JSON) as details
FROM students
```

Answer (score 0):

First, those are not exactly the results I get in Postgres.  Second, it seems like you want a JSON object returned.  So one method is:

```
select id, json_object( array['name', 'age', 'city'], array[name, age::text, city])
from students;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d63cc99d26d86e5d786972ff68501fc8) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

solution:

```
select a.id,cast(row(a.name,a.age,a.city) as row(name varchar,age int,city varchar)) as details from students a
```

it will give you the desired output you want in Athena.